# Is it possible to share the same folder name on two separate drives?

Tags: windows-server-2003, cluster

I have a Windows 2003 cluster that I'm trying to migrate to a new SAN. One of the drives that I'm copying data from has a shared folder (`J:\SharedFolder`)

I need to copy all data from J:\ to T:\ and am planning on `xcopy /a /s /u J:\ T:\`

I guess my questions is if it will cause problems to have two shares with the same name on different drives. This will not be permanent, but I don't want to mess anything up. For a brief period of time, I will have

J:\SharedFolder

AND

T:\SharedFolder

Essentially, this is the opposite of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/210408)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to have two shares with the same name on the same server. What benefit is it to do that anyway? Just copy, unshare one, then share out the new one.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but was hoping for a way out of recreating permissions. If I have to do it, then I have to do it.

Comment: If you use `robocopy /mir` you can copy all security permissions over. You really shouldn't need to set share-level permissions, those are an artifact of the Win9x days. Just control all permissions at the filesystem level, copy those with the files using robocopy, and then give `Everyone` full control at the share level.

Answer (score 1):

First, the folder name shouldn't have a "$" in it, the share name should.

No you can't have multiple shares with the same share name.
Yes you can have multiple folders with the same folder name.

Share names and folder names are separate and should not be treated the exact same way.

Comment: Right. Apologies. I got all turned around. The folder has no "$" in it but it is listed that way as a clustered resource.

Answer (score 0):

If I access `\\servername\SharedFolder$` then how can I select which one should be used if the OS allowed two identical named shares? I see no way that would work.

I see no such problems with having `J:\SharedFolder$`, making it read-only, copying the data (e.g. with the xopy command you mentioned), removeing the share on J: and enabling it on T:

If the copying takes to long you could first make a copy (and then repeat above procedure with a rsync like program instead of xcopy. That would speed things up because you only would copy files which have changed since the initial copy.

Comment: Check out Syncback for doing the synchronization with a GUI tool that has reporting.